Problemas con Mini compilador en c
estoy haciendo un compilador en c que lo hace es que se le suba un array por consola y que en la misma linea este un print el mini compilador debe de hacer un analisis lexico verificando que todo esta bien escrito , un analisis semantico donde tambien se presente un arbol sintactico y un analisis semantico siempre me bota que esta mal escrito ya ya no se que hacer y eso que lo hago bien me imagino que lo demas esta bien escrito pero el problema que tengo es que se me crashea y me da error
Lo que quiero ver es porque me da error si en visual no me marca error y por eso me parece raro y ya intente todo
Más o menos le explico el código debe de hacer que se cree un array y luego se muestre en pantalla con un printf
Osea array[10,20,30] printf(array)
La salida sería la identificación de tokens el mensaje de que se completo el análisis lexico si la línea está bien es escrito luego el árbol semántico de esa línea de codigo y luego un mensaje donde el se completo el análisis semántico y luego un mensaje donde se completa el análisis sintáctico y por último la generación de código osea el contenido de la lista
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100
#define MAX_ARRAYS 10

typedef struct {
    char type[20];
    char value[20];
    int position; // Campo para almacenar la posición del token
} Token;

int arrays[MAX_ARRAYS][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
int array_indices[MAX_ARRAYS] = {0};
int num_arrays = 0;

// Función para imprimir un arreglo de enteros
void printArray(int array_index) {
    printf("Arreglo %d: [", array_index);
    for (int i = 0; i < array_indices[array_index]; ++i) {
        printf("%d", arrays[array_index][i]);
        if (i < array_indices[array_index] - 1)
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

// Función para imprimir el árbol sintáctico
void printSyntaxTree() {
    printf("\nÁrbol Sintáctico: \n\n");
    printf("      Inicio\n");
    printf("         |\n");
    printf("       Operación\n");
    printf("      /     \\\n");
    printf("     Argumento1       Argumento2\n");
    printf("       |\n");
    printf("    Mostrar\n");
    printf("       |\n");
    printf("      Fin\n\n");

    // Código del árbol sintáctico
    printf("void printSyntaxTree() {\n");
    printf("    printf(\"\\nÁrbol Sintáctico: \\n\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"      Inicio\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"         |\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"       Operación\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"      /     \\\\\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"     Argumento1       Argumento2\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"       |\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"    Mostrar\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"       |\\n\");\n");
    printf("    printf(\"      Fin\\n\\n\");\n");
    printf("}\n");
}

// Analizador léxico
Token* lexer(const char* input_string, int* num_tokens) {
    Token* tokens = malloc(sizeof(Token) * (strlen(input_string) + 1));
    if (tokens == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Fallo en la asignación de memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int line_count = 1;

    while (input_string[i] != '\0') {
        if (isspace(input_string[i])) {
            if (input_string[i] == '\n') {
                line_count++;
            }
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (isdigit(input_string[i])) {
            int j = 0;
            while (isdigit(input_string[i])) {
                tokens[index].value[j] = input_string[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            tokens[index].value[j] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "NUMERO");
            tokens[index].position = i - j + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            continue;
        }

        if (input_string[i] == '[') {
            tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
            tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "CORCHETE_IZQ");
            tokens[index].position = i + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (input_string[i] == ']') {
            tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
            tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "CORCHETE_DER");
            tokens[index].position = i + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (strncmp(&input_string[i], "printf", 6) == 0) {
            strncpy(tokens[index].value, "printf", 6);
            tokens[index].value[6] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "PRINTF");
            tokens[index].position = i + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            i += 6;
            continue;
        }

        if (input_string[i] == ';') {
            tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
            tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "PUNTO_COMA");
            tokens[index].position = i + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (input_string[i] == ',') {
            tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
            tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "COMA");
            tokens[index].position = i + 1; // Guardar la posición del token
            index++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (isalpha(input_string[i])) {
            printf("Error léxico en línea %d, posición %d: Carácter no válido: %c\n", line_count, i + 1, input_string[i]);
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (input_string[i]) {
            case ' ':
                i++;
                break;
            case '\n':
                line_count++;
                i++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error léxico en línea %d, posición %d: Carácter no válido: %c\n", line_count, i + 1, input_string[i]);
                exit(1);
        }

        i++;
    }

    *num_tokens = index;
    return tokens;
}

// Analizador sintáctico
void parse(Token* tokens, int num_tokens) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < num_tokens) {
        if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_IZQ") == 0) {
            i++;
            while (i < num_tokens && strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_DER") != 0) {
                if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "NUMERO") == 0) {
                    int value = atoi(tokens[i].value);
                    arrays[num_arrays][array_indices[num_arrays]] = value;
                    array_indices[num_arrays]++;
                } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "COMA") != 0 && strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_DER") != 0) {
                    printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Se esperaba un número o coma.\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position);
                    exit(1);
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_DER") == 0) {
                num_arrays++;
            } else {
                printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Falta corchete derecho.\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position);
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "PRINTF") == 0) {
            i++;
            if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_IZQ") != 0) {
                printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Se esperaba corchete izquierdo.\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position);
                exit(1);
            }
            i++;
            while (i < num_tokens && strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_DER") != 0) {
                if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "PRINTF") == 0) {
                    printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Se esperaba un corchete derecho.\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position);
                    exit(1);
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "CORCHETE_DER") != 0) {
                printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Falta corchete derecho.\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position);
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            printf("Error sintáctico en línea %d, posición %d: Token inesperado: %s\n", tokens[i].position, tokens[i].position, tokens[i].value);
            exit(1);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char input_string[100];

    printf("Este programa permite crear múltiples arreglos de enteros y luego imprimirlos usando printf.\n");
    printf("Ingresa una secuencia de números entre corchetes para crear un arreglo, separados por punto y coma (;).\n");
    printf("Después, ingresa la instrucción printf para imprimir los arreglos.\n");
    printf("Puedes definir múltiples arreglos separados por coma.\n");

    printf("Ingresa la secuencia: ");
    fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin);
    input_string[strcspn(input_string, "\n")] = 0;

    int num_tokens;
    Token* tokens = lexer(input_string, &num_tokens);

    printf("Tokens encontrados:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++) {
        printf("(%s, %s) - Posición: %d\n", tokens[i].type, tokens[i].value, tokens[i].position);
    }

    parse(tokens, num_tokens);
    printSyntaxTree(); // Imprime el árbol sintáctico

    free(tokens);

    return 0;
}

